# Objective-C++ Error: Expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, uiimage, objective-c++

Recently I checked out an old app of mine which at the pint when I stopped working on it, it was still working fine. However now with every time I define the `UIImage *new` I get the error `Expected unqualified-id`.

Below is the method:

```
- (void)endTorsoWithUIImageView:(UIImageView *)flipper andError:(NSError *)clothingManagerError {
    currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol = (direction == 1)? currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol + 1 : currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol - 1;
    [clothingManager notifyAboutMovementInSection:ECOSTorso inDirection:(direction == 1)? ECCDNext : ECCDPrevious];

    if (direction == 1) {
        if (currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol + 2 < [[clothingManager.sectionSetSizes objectAtIndex:0] intValue]) {
            flipper = [[sectionMatrix objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:(currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol + 2) % 4];
            [flipper setHidden:YES];
            [flipper setCenter:(direction == 1)?   CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width + self.outfitView.frame.size.width, flipper.center.y) : CGPointMake(0 - self.outfitView.frame.size.width, flipper.center.y)];
            [flipper setHidden:NO];

            ECChangeDirection dir = (direction == 1)? ECCDNext : ECCDPrevious;
            UIImage *new = [clothingManager updateAfterChangeInDirection:dir forSection:ECOSTorso withError:&clothingManagerError];
            if (new != NULL) {
                [flipper setImage:new];
                [flipper setFrame:CGRectMake(flipper.frame.origin.x, flipper.frame.origin.y, flipper.frame.size.width, [self ratifierForImage:new])];
                [self centerImageView:flipper forFocus:ASTorso takingLoctionIntoAccount:NO forLocation:0];
                [[imageAssetCollection objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:(currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol + 2) % 4
                                                              withObject:new];
            } else {
                // TODO: Report error to google analytics
            }
        }
    } else if (direction == -1) {
        if (currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol - 2 >= 0) {
            flipper = [[sectionMatrix objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:(currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol - 2) % 4];
            [flipper setHidden:YES];
            [flipper setCenter:(direction == 1)? CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width + self.outfitView.frame.size.width, flipper.center.y) : CGPointMake(0 - self.outfitView.frame.size.width, flipper.center.y)];
            [flipper setHidden:NO];

            UIImage *new = (UIImage *)[clothingManager updateAfterChangeInDirection:(direction == 1)? ECCDNext : ECCDPrevious                                                           forSection:ECOSTorso                                                                         withError:&clothingManagerError];
            if (new != NULL) {
                [flipper setImage:new];
                [flipper setFrame:CGRectMake(flipper.frame.origin.x, flipper.frame.origin.y, flipper.frame.size.width, [self ratifierForImage:new])];
                [self centerImageView:flipper forFocus:ASTorso takingLoctionIntoAccount:NO forLocation:0];
                [[imageAssetCollection objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:(currActiveCol.torsoCurrCol + 2) % 4
                                                              withObject:new];
            } else {
                // TODO: Report error to google analytics
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The methods definition is as follows `- (UIImage * _Nullable)updateAfterChangeInDirection:(ECChangeDirection)direction forSection:(ECOutfitSection)ecos withError:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;`. The method itself has no issues returning the specific image or NULL if no image exists.

I am really lost, and would really appreciate any tips.

Comment: do not use "new" as variable name to start with. And do your UIImage check with nil, not NULL . https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as the answer  thank you so much again!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `new` as variable name to start with. And do your `UIImage` check with `nil`, not `NULL` .

[Look here for info on naming properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html)